# Flutter how to change awesome notifications icon background color

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to change the green color of the awesome Notification icon but I can't find where to do it.

[image]

Does anyone know how to change the color?

Answer (score 1):

There's a backgroundColor parameter in AwesomeNotifications().createNotification() method.

Here's the code that worked for me:

```
void triggerNotification() {
  AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
    content: NotificationContent(
      id: 10,
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      channelKey: AppStrings.notificationChannelKey,
      title: AppStrings.appName,
      body: 'Simple Button',
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example since your icon is white and the background is transparent, you can just use the color property

```
await AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
      content: NotificationContent(
          id: 0,
          channelKey: 'my-channel',
          title: 'my-title',
          body: 'my-body',
          color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 101, 147, 233)),
      actionButtons: actionButtons,
    );
```